# How to access attributes of audiocontext

Tags: javascript

```
var audioctx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();

console.log(audioctx.prototype);
```

I tried

```
console.log(typeof(audioctx)) 
console.log(Object.keys(audioctx))
```

They return undefined

I wonder since the audioctx is an object, why the methods/function I tried above were all not working.

Comment: Try `console.log(audioctx);`

Comment: try console.dir(audioctx); for see more regularly properties and methods

Comment: but how to list all properties names?
a=Object.getOwnPropertyNames(audioctx) ;
 console.log(a) also not working